# Is there something similar to onPreExecute and onPostExecute for traditional Threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I was using `AsyncTask` and just switched over to using a traditional `Thread` for reasons not worth going into for the sake of this question.

What can I do to make something execute before and after the thread starts, similar to the functionality of onPre/PostExecute?

For example, let's say I want to display a loading circle before the thread starts, and dismiss it when it finishes. How would I do that?

For the post-execution bit, I'm using thread.join() and it seems to do the trick. I'm not sure if that's the way to go about it though, or how to do something pre-execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What can I do to make something execute before and after the thread starts, similar to the functionality of onPre/PostExecute?

`onPreExecute()` -> statements you execute before calling `start()` on your `Thread`

`onPostExecute()` -> call `runOnUiThread()`, or `post()` on a `View`, from your `Thread`, supplying a `Runnable` to be executed on the main application thread

> How would I do that?

Ideally, you wouldn't. Progress dialogs suck. Put a progress indicator in your UI somewhere (e.g., action bar, title bar), and disable the few things the user cannot safely do while your thread is in operation.

That being said, you'd presumably display the `DialogFragment` before executing the thread, then remove the fragment once the thread is completed via the above mechanisms.

> For the post-execution bit, I'm using thread.join() and it seems to do the trick.

Ick. That will block whatever thread you are on, and if that's the main application thread, that's really bad.

---

**UPDATE**

Example of `runOnUiThread()`:

```
new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    // do cool stuff
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        // do other cool stuff quickly on the main application thread
      }
    );
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do the post execute?

Comment: @TheBeatlemaniac: See update. This assumes the code in question is in a method in your activity.

Comment: It isn't in my Activity, sorry I didn't specify.

Comment: In a class that implements Runnable

Comment: @TheBeatlemaniac: Then pass the `Activity` into that class, and call `runOnUiThread()` on the activity. Or, pass a `View` into that class, and call `post()` on the `View`.

Comment: It works, thanks! Though I don't think I'm seeing the stuff that's supposed to happen before thread.start()...

Comment: what will happen if we put `Thread.sleep(10000)` instead `// do cool stuff` and then change device orientation ...

Comment: This is almost definitely an unrelated problem, though. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Selvin: You'll have to kick up your sophistication a notch, perhaps by having the `Thread` (or, better yet, `AsyncTask`) be managed by a retained `Fragment`. That starts to get beyond "StackOverflow answer" and into "chapter in a book", particularly given the scope of the original question, though.

Answer (score 0):

Latches(such as CountDownLatch) maybe an another useful way to do it.

```
public class TestHarness {
public long timeTasks(int nThreads, final Runnable task)
        throws InterruptedException {
    final CountDownLatch startGate = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final CountDownLatch endGate = new CountDownLatch(nThreads);

    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    startGate.await();
                    try {
                        task.run();
                    } finally {
                        endGate.countDown();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) { }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    startGate.countDown();
    endGate.await();
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    return end-start;
}
```

}